# How can I clear a interval which is stored into a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my code:

```js
var isBlinking = null;

function blink(el) {
    el.fadeTo('slow', 0.2).fadeTo('slow', .8);
}

$('.start').on('click', function(){
  isBlinking = setInterval(function () {
    blink($('div'));
  }, 1);
})

$('.stop').on('click', function(){
  clearInterval(isBlinking);
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<br />
<input type="button" class="start" value="start" />
<input type="button" class="stop" value="stop" />
```

As you see, `stop` button doesn't stop blinking. What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: you should bind `.stop` class not `.end` $('. stop').on('click', function(){
  clearInterval(isBlinking);
})

Comment: Sorry it was a typo, edited.  @Rakib

Comment: here you go: https://jsfiddle.net/j6nfwyze/3/ actually your code is working just use 500 for setInterval.

Comment: @Rakib Thank you, upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code adds an function to the `.queue()` of the `$("div")` jQuery object at each `setInterval()` call. You can call `.stop(true, true)` or `.finish()` on `$("div")` finish the current animation and clear the animation queue at the jQuery object

```js
var isBlinking = null;

function blink(el) {
    el.fadeTo('slow', 0.2).fadeTo('slow', .8);
}

$('.start').one('click', function(){
  isBlinking = setInterval(function () {
    blink($('div'));
  }, 1);
})

$('.stop').on('click', function(){
  clearInterval(isBlinking);
  $("div").finish()
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<br />
<input type="button" class="start" value="start" />
<input type="button" class="stop" value="stop" />
```

Answer (score 3):

Firsly, the button has the class `.stop`, not `.end`
Secondly, you've set an interval of 0.001 seconds *(1 millisecond)*, meaning you're queing up a large number of animations that won't just go away when you stop the interval.

You have to target the right class, and then set the interval to a more appropriate time

```js
var isBlinking = null;

function blink(el) {
    el.fadeTo('slow', 0.2).fadeTo('slow', .8);
}

$('.start').on('click', function(){
  isBlinking = setInterval(function () {
    blink($('div'));
  }, 1400);
  blink($('div'))
})

$('.stop').on('click', function(){
  clearInterval(isBlinking);
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<br />
<input type="button" class="start" value="start" />
<input type="button" class="stop" value="stop" />
```

A much better approach, that would let you have any number of timers, would be to use jQuery's `data()` to store the reference to the interval, rather than a variable, and call `stop()` to make sure the animation stops

```js
function blink(el) {
  el.fadeTo('slow', 0.2).fadeTo('slow', .8);
}

$('.start').on('click', function(){
  $(this).data('timer', setInterval(function () {
   blink($('div'));
  }, 1400));
  blink($('div'))
});

$('.stop').on('click', function(){
  clearInterval($(this).prev().stop(true,true).data('timer'));
});
```

```css
div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<br />
<input type="button" class="start" value="start" />
<input type="button" class="stop" value="stop" />
```

Comment: Also as a unrelated question, can you please tell me how can I get the error message in `.catch` block? https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8e20c1abfa6d3b597999c3a66044080d#file-gistfile1-txt-L28

Comment: Should just be in the arguments, as in `.catch((errors) => { ...`

Answer (score 1):

you have problem in your "delay" from setInterval

```
  isBlinking = setInterval(function () {
    blink($('div'));
  }, 1000);
```

don't use interval, use stop()

```js
var isBlinking = -1;

function blink(el) {
    el.fadeTo('slow', 0.2).fadeTo('slow', .8, function() {
        blink(el);
    });
}

$('.start').on('click', function(){
  blink($('div'));
})

$('.stop').on('click', function(){
  $('div').stop(true).removeAttr('style');
})
```

```css
div{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<br />
<input type="button" class="start" value="start" />
<input type="button" class="stop" value="stop" />
```